# After modifying DOM how to make sure that DOM is ready again

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, dom

**Let's do code first:**

```
$(function(){

   //Step-2) Load and a template from server and APPEND to BODY  
   function loadTemplate(path, callback) {
        $.get(path, null, function (t) {
            $('body').append(t);
        }, 'text');

        if (callback != undefined && typeof (callback) == 'function') {
            callback.apply(window);
        }
    }

    //Step-3) a callback method
    function showProduct() {
        //setTimeout(function () {
        //    $('#prodBasicView').tmpl(prod).appendTo('#prodView');
        //}, 100);

        alert($('#prodBasicView').length); // it alerts 0, But I am expecting 1

    }

    //Step-1) initiating loading template
    loadTemplate('/template/remote-template2.htm', showProduct);
});
```

**remote-template2.htm :-**

```
     <div id="prodBasicView" style="display:none;">
       <div class="myProd">
        <h3> Product Name</h3>
           <span>Price: $ 700 </span>
       </div>
     </div>
```

**ISSUE:**

- *loadTemplate* method successfully loaded a template (*remote-template2.htm*) and append to body.
- After successfully loaded the template the passing callback function *showProduct* method get fired.
- Inside *showProduct* method I am trying to use loaded template (*$('#prodBasicView')*) but it returns empty array.
- **But if I delay the execution of *showProduct* with few millisecond it works** but I don't think its a good practice
- The above point seems to be appended DOM elements are not ready
- **HOW TO MAKE SURE MODIFIED/ MANIPULATED DOM IS READY AGAIN BEFORE USING THEM ??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you just need to put the callback-calling code within the `$.get` callback, like so:

```
function loadTemplate(path, callback) {
    $.get(path, null, function (t) {
        $('body').append(t);
        if (callback != undefined && typeof (callback) == 'function') {
            callback.apply(window);
        }
    }, 'text');
}
```

Comment: Yes callback is invoking from `$.get` callback using javascript's **apply** method

Comment: @LPremchandra: I'm afraid I do not understand your comment. Is there a problem with the code I provided? In your original code, the `if (callback !=`... line was outside of the `$.get` function's callback; by putting it inside, I ensure that it does not get called until that callback does (that is, after the `$('body').append(t);` call).

Comment: :) Thanks Dragoon Wraith. I was thinking my callback is inside the `$.get` callback. Its is a mistake in my code but understanding was correct.  **Thanks a lots**

Answer (score 1):

Execute your `callback` in the ajax callback handler. (Because ajax works **asynchronously**)

```
   function loadTemplate(path, callback) {
        $.get(path, null, function (t) {
            $('body').append(t);
            if (callback != undefined && typeof (callback) == 'function') {
               callback.apply(window);
            }
        }, 'text');
    }
```

Comment: My actual Callback method **showProduct** is calling from inside ajax callback handler by passing it into **loadTemplate** method

Comment: @LPremchandra Is it? Check the code and see what is different?

Comment: A mistake in my code. Thanks it should be inside ajax callback